# How do I find available rooms using LINQ, when there are more than one of each room type?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the capability of a customer placing a booking after inputting their selected dates and specifying their room choice. It is at this point - checking availability - that I make use of the following LINQ expression:

```
var availRooms = db.Rooms.Where(room => room.RoomTypeID == roomChoiceID)
    .Where(m => m.Bookings.All(r => r.Departure <= model.Arrival || 
                                    r.Arrival >= model.Departure));
```

(`roomChoiceID` is obtained by querying the db with the user's inputted room choice)

This works fine, up until I decide to book two rooms of the same room type on the same dates. (E.g. booking a family room for 10/06/18 - 12/06/18 works fine, but then attempting to book the second family room on these dates gives an error). I am totally unsure how I can use LINQ to give me the room which has the same room type (family in my example), and is NOT booked on the dates I input.

Comment: You need to tell us what error you are getting and also tell us which line of code gives the error.

Comment: The query does not return a list of rooms when the same room type and dates are selected. However, choosing unique dates returns a list of rooms to availRooms.

Comment: The logic seems to be sound. Are you sure you've set up foreign keys correctly? How do you define your database model?

Comment: Please add sample data so everyone's on the same page (i.e. `var rooms = new List<Room> { // populate a list here }` then execute the query against the static list so we can all play along

Comment: Yes, a [mcve] would be useful. Sample data, query, expected output and actual output.

Comment: What makes you think the problem is with this LINQ? You said the error occurs when you attempt to *book* the room, which presumably comes afterward. You're not trying to book the same room twice, are you?

Comment: In your query,  you are returning ALL the rooms with the same type, not only the available ones. Is that what you intended? The problem may be that you are trying to book the same room and not 2 separate rooms. Your database may not be allowing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var availRooms = db.Rooms.Where(room => room.RoomTypeID == roomChoiceID && (!room.Booking.Any(b => (b.Departure >= model.Departure && b.Arrival <= model.Arrival)));
```

Or, using linq expression:

```
var availRooms = from room in rooms
where room.RoomTypeID == roomChoiceID
&& (!room.Bookings.Any(b => b.Departure >= model.Departure && b.Arrival <= model.Arrival))
select room;
```

Explanation:
In the query above, it will return all rooms where has not booking within the Arrival and Departure range.